# Test if a string contains any of the strings from an array

Tags: java, string, if-statement

How do I test a string to see if it contains any of the strings from an array?

Instead of using

```
if (string.contains(item1) || string.contains(item2) || string.contains(item3))
```

Comment: Are you asking if a string is **equal** to any of the strings in the array, or **contains** any of the strings from in the array?

Comment: You want to check if any string from the array is a substring of your input string? Or you want to check if your input string *equals* one of the string in the array? Can you be more precise?

Comment: contains, so that it takes a line and sees if it contains any of the words from a list (stored as an array of strings)

Answer (score 266, accepted):

EDIT: Here is an update using the Java 8 Streaming API. So much cleaner. Can still be combined with regular expressions too.

```
public static boolean stringContainsItemFromList(String inputStr, String[] items) {
    return Arrays.stream(items).anyMatch(inputStr::contains);
}
```

Also, if we change the input type to a List instead of an array we can use `items.stream().anyMatch(inputStr::contains)`.

You can also use `.filter(inputStr::contains).findAny()` if you wish to return the matching string.

**Important:** the above code can be done using `parallelStream()` but most of the time this will actually hinder performance. See [this question for more details on parallel streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375176/should-i-always-use-a-parallel-stream-when-possible).

---

Original slightly dated answer:

Here is a (VERY BASIC) static method. Note that it is case sensitive on the comparison strings. A **primitive** way to make it case insensitive would be to call `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` on both the input and test strings.

If you need to do anything more complicated than this, I would recommend looking at the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes and learning how to do some regular expressions. Once you understand those, you can use those classes or the `String.matches()` helper method.

```
public static boolean stringContainsItemFromList(String inputStr, String[] items)
{
    for(int i =0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        if(inputStr.contains(items[i]))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How to use it with regular expression @gnomed

Comment: How can we make the first implementation case sensitive ?

Comment: The implementations are case sensitive already. I also have instructions for how to make it case insensitive in the bottom paragraphs of the answer.

Comment: parallelStream uses a minimum batch size of 1024, it won't actually parallelise small lists. It's a footgun.

Comment: @CallumRogers true, I kind of left it in just so people think about it, but agree the vast majority of the time it will not make much difference (or actually be a detriment) compared to a non-parallel stream. Will try to call that out more in the answer.

Comment: Still prefer the "old" answer, more supported and sufficient in most cases.

Comment: Is there a better way if you want to check it for characters? Because I would have to convert my `char[]` to `String[]` which doesn't seem right.

Comment: To make it all primitve char logic you could convert the inputStr to a char[] and then implement the "contains" as a simple inner loop linear search of the `char[] inputStr` array with a primitive `==` check for each character. If you really wanted to optimize performance you could also sort and deduplicate the input str characters and search it using binary search for each character in your input `char[] items`.

Answer (score 60):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
```

[String Utils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

Use:

```
StringUtils.indexOfAny(inputString, new String[]{item1, item2, item3})
```

It will return the index of the string found or -1 if none is found.

Comment: JFI: I hoped this implementation to iterate only once over the inputString, but I looked at the code in StringUtils, and sadly it's just doing N calls of the default indexOf.

Comment: Maybe on commons3 the implementation is better!

Comment: Nope, still just iterates over the Strings in org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils:
        for (int i = 0; i < searchStrs.length; i++) { 
            CharSequenceUtils.indexOf(str, search, 0);
            ....

Comment: This does not return the index of the string found (from the array), only the index of the position the string was found at.

Answer (score 36):

You can use [String#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method like this:

```
System.out.printf("Matches - [%s]%n", string.matches("^.*?(item1|item2|item3).*$"));
```

Answer (score 23):

If you use **Java 8** or above, you can rely on the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to do such thing:

```
public static boolean containsItemFromArray(String inputString, String[] items) {
    // Convert the array of String items as a Stream
    // For each element of the Stream call inputString.contains(element)
    // If you have any match returns true, false otherwise
    return Arrays.stream(items).anyMatch(inputString::contains);
}
```

Assuming that you have a big array of big `String` to test you could also launch the search in parallel by calling [`parallel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--), the code would then be:

```
return Arrays.stream(items).parallel().anyMatch(inputString::contains);
```

Comment: One strange thing I noticed,  I have two item in the String list, I found out, when i use 'parallel' it will not return the correct results. (even if it contains the value).

Comment: @Charles.C that's weird I can't reproduce on my side.

Comment: I am pretty sure parallelizing the stream would be suboptimal here  unless input string was long (~ 500 chars). Instead if the array was large, It would probably be better to partitition the array and run each of those in parallel.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way would probably be to convert the array into a java.util.ArrayList.  Once it is in an arraylist, you can easily leverage the contains method.

```
public static boolean bagOfWords(String str)
{
    String[] words = {"word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5"};  
    return (Arrays.asList(words).contains(str));
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. OP is asking if `string` contains any `String`s in the array, not if any `String`s in the array contain `string`.

Comment: @BeauGrantham I was thinking this too, but the OP is using `.equals()` in their post, which is very confusing. I reckon they need to edit their question

Comment: @BeauGrantham Man I couldn't sworn I understood the problem. Maybe the question needs to be clarified a bit more?

Comment: The question is vague, I agree. Maybe this is indeed what they are looking for.

Comment: No, this kind of inverse direction won't work, you should check if String contains ONE of the values given and NOT if the values gives contain the string.

Comment: Question is the opposite

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (Arrays.stream(new String[] {item1, item2, item3}).anyMatch(inputStr::contains))
```

Comment: Question is the opposite: Does the target string contain any of the list’s strings.

Comment: `stream()` and `anyMatch()` requires API level 24 or above

Comment: @DilankaLaksiri not really, those methods have been available since Java 8. And the latest version of Java is 16, so what "API level 24" are you referring to?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I'm talking about the Android API level.

Comment: Ok, good. But this question was not about Android :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution :

```
public static boolean containsAny(String str, String[] words)
{
   boolean bResult=false; // will be set, if any of the words are found
   //String[] words = {"word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5"};

   List<String> list = Arrays.asList(words);
   for (String word: list ) {
       boolean bFound = str.contains(word);
       if (bFound) {bResult=bFound; break;}
   }
   return bResult;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since version 3.4 Apache Common Lang 3 implement the [containsAny](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsAny-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method.

Comment: That checks for Char array

Answer (score 1):

A more groovyesque approach would be to use **inject** in combination with **metaClass**:

I would to love to say:

```
String myInput="This string is FORBIDDEN"
myInput.containsAny(["FORBIDDEN","NOT_ALLOWED"]) //=>true
```

And the method would be:

```
myInput.metaClass.containsAny={List<String> notAllowedTerms->
   notAllowedTerms?.inject(false,{found,term->found || delegate.contains(term)})
}
```

If you need **containsAny** to be present for any future String variable then add the method to the class instead of the object:

```
String.metaClass.containsAny={notAllowedTerms->
   notAllowedTerms?.inject(false,{found,term->found || delegate.contains(term)})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do like this:

```
if (string.matches("^.*?((?i)item1|item2|item3).*$"))
```

```
(?i): used for case insensitive
.*? & .*$: used for checking whether it is present anywhere in between the string.
```

Comment: I believe wrapping the ends with `.*` makes the `?` and `$` redundant, as `.*` means "zero or more of any characters" (with some control char caveats)

Answer (score 0):

And if you are looking for case insensitive match, use pattern

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bitem1 |item2\\b",java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) { 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are seraching for **whole** **words** you can do this that works **case** **insensitive**.

```
private boolean containsKeyword(String line, String[] keywords)
{
    String[] inputWords = line.split(" ");

    for (String inputWord : inputWords)
    {
        for (String keyword : keywords)
        {
            if (inputWord.equalsIgnoreCase(keyword))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in Kotlin

```
if ( arrayOf("one", "two", "three").find{ "onetw".contains(it) } != null ) {
    doStuff()
}
```

Comment: Not sure if adding a badly formatted answer in a different language than what had been asked for 9 years ago is appropriate.

Comment: @ThomasHirsch Why wouldn't it be? It's straightforward and definitely more useful today

Answer (score 0):

In Apache common lang 3 support check contains any Strings. Try it:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

...

if(StringUtils.containsAny(string, item1, item2, item3)){
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The below should work for you assuming **Strings** is the array that you are searching within:

```
Arrays.binarySearch(Strings,"mykeytosearch",mysearchComparator);
```

where mykeytosearch is the string that you want to test for existence within the array.
mysearchComparator - is a comparator that would be used to compare strings.

Refer to [Arrays.binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28T%5B%5D,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29) for more information.

Comment: It should be noted that binarySearch works only on array that are sorted, either naturally or by the given comparator (if such is given).

Answer (score -6):

```
if (Arrays.asList(array).contains(string))
```

Comment: Question is the opposite: Does the target string contain any of the list’s strings.