# Checking if String x equals any of the Strings from String[]

Tags: java

I am trying to set a boolean true if a user-entered string equals any of the strings from a string array.

I have improvised and came up with this

```
String[] cancelWords = {"cancel", "nevermind", "scratch that"};
boolean valueEqualsCancel = true;
for(String cancelWord : cancelWords) {
  if(!valueEqualsCancel) break;
  valueEqualsCancel =  valueEqualsCancel && value.equals(cancelWord);
}
```

But `valueEqualsCancel` is never true.

Any tips?

Comment: Your loop does not quit when you find "cancel". It will be set to false since "nevermind" and "scratch that" do not equal "cancel".

Comment: Once you find a match, exit the loop.  Don't cycle over the remaining elements.

Comment: check this for jdk8 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992100/test-if-a-string-contains-any-of-the-strings-from-an-array?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**valueEqualsCancel** is never true because you don't exit from the loop when you find the **cancelWord**.

In order to reach the break statement you need valueEqualsCancel to be false.

If you for example search for "cancel" after the first loop the variable valueEqualsCancel is:

```
valueEqualsCancel =  valueEqualsCancel && value.equals(cancelWord) = TRUE && TRUE = TRUE;
```

so on the second loop you don't break. Then you evaluate the expression again

```
valueEqualsCancel =  valueEqualsCancel && value.equals(cancelWord) = TRUE && FALSE = FALSE;
```

therefore on third loop you will exit and valueEqualsCancel is false.

You can correct your code in this way:

```
String[] cancelWords = {"cancel", "nevermind", "scratch that"};
boolean found = false;
for(String cancelWord : cancelWords) {
  found = value.equals(cancelWord);
  if (found) break;
}
```

Comment: The OP says nothing about the list being sorted, not the number of times the search would be performed.  Thus I don't know if the binarySearch comment is appropriate.

Comment: This looks like the best answer to me. Writing a for loop to search an array and break when a result is found is a pattern that I use frequently in Java.

Answer (score 24):

You can do something like:

```
Arrays.asList(cancelWords).contains(value)
```

(see [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29))

If you're going to be doing multiple queries like this, then put all of your words in a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and query that.

Comment: +1 for putting the words into a set. I disagree with the `asList` approach, though, because that adds quite a bit of overhead. It's fine for small arrays, but it would have a noticeable effect on large data sets.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the upvote :) Why do you say `asList` adds overhead? It creates a list backed directly by whatever array you pass in (no copying involved), so there is very little associated cost, regardless of the array size.

Comment: I stand corrected. I assumed that creating the list was O(n).

Answer (score 6):

Convert the `Array` to a `List` and then use the `contains` method to check.

`Arrays.asList(cancelWords).contains(value)`

Comment: contains will not do because value has to be exactly as a string from the array. e.g. value might be "cancel that" but that wouldn't equal "cancel" from the array.

Comment: With the `equals` method in the question. I think the OP is trying to do the same.

Comment: This is a good answer in that it encourages the OP to use constructs that already exist instead of coding something by hand.  I can't comment on whether or not the exact solution presented is what the OP needs.

Comment: @MattSmith [`Collection.contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a 2-liner using Java 8 that is easy to read:

```
String[] cancelWords = {"cancel", "nevermind", "scratch that"};
boolean valueEqualsCancel = Arrays.stream(cancelWords).anyMatch(value::equals);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) you can use [`StringUtils.equalsAny()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#equalsAny-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-):

```
String[] cancelWords = {"cancel", "nevermind", "scratch that"};
boolean valueEqualsCancel = StringUtils.equalsAny(value, cancelWords);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach(string thisWord in cancelWords)
    if thisWord.equals(value)
       return true;

 return false;    // Fall-through
```

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this pseudocode.  I don't understand the -1.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial value is off, and the flow can be improved:

```
String[] cancelWords = {"cancel", "nevermind", "scratch that"};
boolean valueEqualsCancel = false; // fix
for(String cancelWord : cancelWords) {
  if(value.equals(cancelWord)) {
    valueEqualsCancel =  true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
public boolean containsWord(String word, String[] words) {
   for(String cancelWord : words) {
      if(word.equals(cancelWord)) {
        return true;
      }
   }
   return false;

}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should help:-

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class check4 {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       String value = scan.nextLine().toString();
       String[] cancelWords = {"cancel", "nevermind", "scratch that"};
       boolean valueEqualsCancel = false;
       for(int i=0;i<cancelWords.length;i++) {
          if(value.equals(cancelWords[i])) {
             valueEqualsCancel = true;
             break;
          }
       }
       System.out.println(valueEqualsCancel);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
camel
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: Doesn't this always output `true` regardless of the input?

Comment: @NullUserException : You are correct,i made an edit,this should help

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 String[] cancelWords = {"cancel", "nevermind", "scratch that"};     
  boolean valueEqualsCancel = true;     
  for(String cancelWord : cancelWords) {      
  if(!valueEqualsCancel) break;     
   valueEqualsCancel =  !(valueEqualsCancel && value.equals(cancelWord));     
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Method

```
public static boolean  isContainsWords(String[] words,String Targent){

               boolean flag;
               for(String buf : words){
                     if(buf.equals(Targent))
                          return flag = true;
               }
               return flag = false;

}
```

It seems perfect

Comment: What's the point of creating `flag` if you never use its value?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that fits best to your situation depends a bit on the number of cancel words and the necessity to compare case insensitive or not. I'Ve added code for two possbile ways to implement:

```
// I would use a HashSet which needs constant time to compare, even with long lists of cancel words
// Note, that the use of toLowerCase() makes the comparison case insensitive.
@Test
public final void test2() {
    String value = "nevermind";
    HashSet<String> cancelWords = new HashSet<String>();
    cancelWords.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"cancel", "nevermind", "scratch that"}));

    boolean valueEqualsCancel = cancelWords.contains(value.toLowerCase());
    System.out.println("test2: " + valueEqualsCancel);
}

// You might like to know, which cancel word it was
@Test
public final void test3() {
    String value = "nevermind";
    String[] cancelWords = {"cancel", "nevermind", "scratch that"};
    Arrays.sort(cancelWords); // Prepare for binary search

    // The returned value indicates either which cancel word was used or, that nothing was found with result < 0.
    System.out.println("test3: nevermind " + Arrays.binarySearch(cancelWords, "nevermind"));
    System.out.println("test3: cancel " + Arrays.binarySearch(cancelWords, "cancel"));
    System.out.println("test3: something totally different " + Arrays.binarySearch(cancelWords, "something totally different"));
}
```