# Checking Multiple strings with if, else if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I am creating a simple lift programme in java. I want to to have four users that are allowed to use the lift i have already got it working for 1 but i cant figure out how to check multiple strings using the one if statement.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Username

{
public static void main (String[]args)
{

    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    String name; 


    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    name = kb.nextLine();
    if (name.equals("barry "))
        System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");


    Scanner f = new Scanner(System.in);
    int floor;


    System.out.println("What floor do you want to go to ");
    floor = f.nextInt();

    if (floor >7)
        System.out.println("Invalid entry");
    else if (floor <= 7)
        System.out.println("Entry valid");



    }

    }
```

Comment: Hopefully this is homework and not the beginnings of a real elevator control system. Do you know how to check for the presence of the supplied string in an array of strings?

Comment: Side note: You don't need to say `else if (floor<=7)`; just `else` is good enough, because if we get there we already know that `floor<=7` must be true.  (Adding a redundant condition like this _could_ lead to "might not have been initialized" errors in some cases.)

Comment: no im trying to figure it out now, ive now got the strings in an array and i am trying to figure out what to write for the user input statement

Answer (score 1):

Check out this related question:

[Test if a string contains any of the strings from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992100/test-if-a-string-contains-any-of-the-strings-from-an-array)

Basically, put the names into an Array of strings, and compare the name entered with each name in the Array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the OR symbol "||" or "|".

Such as `if (name.equals("barry ") || name.equals("sara"))`

For future reference the difference between the two is "||" short circuits. In this situtation, if barry is the name then the second statement for checking against sara will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

basically, you need an "Or" gate, this would work:

```
if(name.equals("name1")||name.equals("name2")||name.equals("name3"))
```

etc...