# Check if String contains words that are set in an array android studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I am trying to check if a string is valid by checking if it contains special words that are set in an array

```
String email = "this@webmaster";
    tv.setText(Boolean.toString(checkEmailValidity(email)));

}

public boolean checkEmailValidity(String email) {

    String[] specialWords = {"webmaster", "government"};
    if( email.contains(specialWords.toString())||email.contains(" ")){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The result is always true so the statement that checks the email with the specialWords is not good. What can I do?

Comment: "this@webmaster" has "webmaster" in itself, so it returns true, what did you expect?

Comment: I wanted it to return false if the email contained one of the special words. I found the logical error thank you as I needed to insert ! in front of email.contains(specialWords.toString()). Thank you for the explanation

Comment: from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992100/test-if-a-string-contains-any-of-the-strings-from-an-array) : `public static boolean stringContainsItemFromList(String inputStr, String[] items) {
    return Arrays.stream(items).parallel().anyMatch(inputStr::contains);
}`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using java 8 you can do this way

```
return Arrays.stream(specialwords).parallel().anyMatch(email::contains);
```

Comment: `parallel()` is overkill for something like this.

Comment: Also note that OP returns `false` when `contains()` return true, so you need to use `noneMatch()` instead.

Comment: Yes.  Parallel is an overkill I agree.

Comment: @Andreas Don't tell _him_ that, he just copied the answer from here: [Test if a string contains any of the strings from an array](//stackoverflow.com/a/8995988)

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```
public static boolean checkEmailValidity(String email) {
        String[] specialWords = {"webmaster", "government"};
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(specialWords));
    return set.contains(email);
    }
```

**This is for your code:**

```
public static boolean checkEmailValidity(String email) {
        String[] specialWords = {"webmaster", "government"};
        boolean flag = false;
        if (!email.contains(" ")) {
            for (int index = 0; index < specialWords.length; index++) {
                if (email.contains(specialWords[index].toString())) {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:webmaster|government)\\b");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(email);
boolean contains = regexMatcher.find();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String email = "this@webmaster";
    tv.setText(Boolean.toString(checkEmailValidity(email)));


public boolean checkEmailValidity(String email) {

    String[] specialWords = {"webmaster", "government"};
    if( email.contains(specialWords.get(0))||email.contains(specialWords.get(1))){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What if there was more than 2 special words?
U should use `forech` in this case.

Comment: It is to handle the task at hand, as i said before in the comment, there is a general solution.