# How to check if some of the text data appears on the page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I would like to check if the page has a specific text. Best if I could check out a few texts right away.

For example, if there are "client", "customer", "order"

Here is the HTML code.

```html
<div class="findText"><span>Example text. Football.</span></div>
```

After checking this I would use if condition as in here. This is my attempt to do this, but this is not the best option. Besides I can not check more words, I tried with || only.

```
 if(driver.getPageSource().contains("google"))  {

                driver.close();
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
                }
```

Besides, is it possible to throw a whole list of words in large numbers to check if they exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(stringContainsItemFromList(driver.getPageSource(), new String[] {"google", "otherword"))
{
    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
}

 public static boolean stringContainsItemFromList(String inputStr, String[] items)
    {
        for(int i =0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            if(inputStr.contains(items[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

stringContainsItemFromList() method from [Test if a string contains any of the strings from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992100/test-if-a-string-contains-any-of-the-strings-from-an-array)

If you want to just get the text of that element you could use something like this instead of driver.getPageSource()...

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.findText > span")).getText();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm currently testing this approach. Looks like its working. But, it is possible to do the same while not using .getPageSource? Like using this HTML code that i posted.

Comment: yeah you could do something like this for example  (see updated post for better formatting)
                                                
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.findText > span")).getText()

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Java 8 Streaming API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    private static final String[] positiveWords = {"love", "kiss", "happy"};

    public static boolean containsPositiveWords(String enteredText, String[] positiveWords) {
        return Arrays.stream(positiveWords).parallel().anyMatch(enteredText::contains);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String enteredText1 = " Yo I love the world!";
        String enteredText2 = "I like to code.";
        System.out.println(containsPositiveWords(enteredText1, positiveWords));
        System.out.println(containsPositiveWords(enteredText2, positiveWords));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

You can also use ArrayList by using the .parallelStream() instead.