# Test if string contains anything from an array of strings (kotlin)

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin, contains

I'm new to Kotlin (I have a Java background) and I can't seem to figure out how to check whether a string contains a match from a list of keywords.

What I want to do is check if a string contains a match from an array of keywords **(case-insensitive please)**. If so, print out the keyword(s) that was matched and the string that contained the keyword. (I will be looping over a bunch of strings in a file).

Here's an MVE for starters:

```
val keywords = arrayOf("foo", "bar", "spam")

fun search(content: String) {
    var match = <return an array of the keywords that content contained>
    if(match.size > 0) {
          println("Found match(es): " + match + "\n" + content)
    }
}   

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var str = "I found food in the barn"
    search(str) //should print out that foo and bar were a match
}
```

As a start (this ignores the 'match' variable and getting-a-list-of-keywords-matched), I tried using the following if statement according with what I found at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992100/test-if-a-string-contains-any-of-the-strings-from-an-array),

```
if(Arrays.stream(keywords).parallel().anyMatch(content::contains))
```

but it put a squiggly line under "content" and gave me this error

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments
>   supplied:  public operator fun CharSequence.contains(char: Char,
>   ignoreCase: Boolean = ...): Boolean defined in kotlin.text public
>   operator fun CharSequence.contains(other: CharSequence, ignoreCase:
>   Boolean = ...): Boolean defined in kotlin.text @InlineOnly public
>   inline operator fun CharSequence.contains(regex: Regex): Boolean
>   defined in kotlin.text

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the [`filter`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) function to leave only those keywords contained in `content`:

```
val match = keywords.filter { it in content }
```

Here `match` is a `List<String>`. If you want to get an array in the result, you can add `.toTypedArray()` call.

`in` operator in the expression `it in content` is the same as `content.contains(it)`.

If you want to have case insensitive match, you need to specify `ignoreCase` parameter when calling `contains`:

```
val match = keywords.filter { content.contains(it, ignoreCase = true) }
```

Comment: Looks great, but another question though: how could I change search to a boolean function that only returns whether or not a keyword was found in content? Is there an easy one-liner solution to that?

Comment: Replace `filter` with `any`.

Answer (score 4):

Another obvious choice is using a regex doing case-insensitive matching:

```
arrayOf("foo", "bar", "spam").joinToString(prefix = "(?i)", separator = "|").toRegex())
```

Glues together a pattern with a prefixed inline `(?i)` incase-sensitive modifier, and alternations between the keywords: `(?i)foo|bar|spam`

[Sample Code](https://ideone.com/IPX5KV):

```
private val keywords = arrayOf("foo", "bar", "spam")
private val pattern = keywords.joinToString(prefix = "(?i)", separator = "|")
private val rx = pattern.toRegex()

fun findKeyword(content: String): ArrayList<String> { 
    var result = ArrayList<String>()
    rx.findAll(content).forEach { result.add(it.value) }
    return result
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) { 
    println(findKeyword("Some spam and a lot of bar"));
}
```

The regex approach could be handy if you are after some more complex matching, e.g. non-/overlapping matches adding word boundaries `\b`, etc.

Comment: How would I modify it to match whole keywords only? (Eg If my keyword is 'foo', I only want to match the word 'foo' in the sentence, and not 'food')

Comment: @takanuva15 `keywords.joinToString(prefix = "(?i)\\b", separator = "\\b|\\b", postfix = "\\b")`

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach without Streams:

```
fun String.containsAnyOfIgnoreCase(keywords: List<String>): Boolean {
    for (keyword in keywords) {
        if (this.contains(keyword, true)) return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Usage:

```
"test string".containsAnyOfIgnoreCase(listOf("abc","test"))
```

Comment: Why would you rewrite the wheel?

Answer (score 3):

I think `Any` is the efficient way.

```
fun findMatch(s: String, strings: List<String>): Boolean {
    return strings.any { s.contains(it) }
}
 
fun main() {
    val today = "Wednesday"
    val weekend = listOf("Sat", "Sun")
    println(if (findMatch(today, weekend)) "Yes" else "No") // No
}
```

reference: [click here](https://www.techiedelight.com/check-if-string-contains-any-of-the-given-substrings-in-kotlin/#:%7E:text=Using%20any()%20function&text=To%20check%20if%20a%20string%20contains%20a%20substring%2C%20use%20the,()%20function%20as%20the%20predicate.&text=That%27s%20all%20about%20checking%20if,the%20given%20substrings%20in%20Kotlin.)