# Java, comparing Strings using parallelStream().anyMatch() and contains() one version works another doesn't

Tags: java, java-stream

I aimed to rework the code found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995988
But this proved unsuccessful.
I got an idea from here: https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/java/lambda-list-contains-a-substring.html

And my idea worked, but I suspect it is bad code and I'd like to know why the StackOverflow rework I did does not work as anticipated.

I'll present both bits of code in 1 block. Simply switch which "if" line is commented and not commented to go between the working and not working versions.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> result0 = Arrays.asList("/Videos/Templates/file.mp4", "/Videos/Templates/file2.mp4", "/Videos/Templates/file3.mp4");
        List<String> result2 = Arrays.asList("/Videos/Templates/file.mp4.sha256");

        for (int i = 0; i < result0.size(); i++) {

            List<String> finalResult = result0;
            int finalI = i;
            // if (result2.parallelStream().anyMatch(x -> x.contains(finalResult.get(finalI)))) {
            if (result2.parallelStream().anyMatch(finalResult.get(finalI)::contains)){
                System.out.println("sha matches files: " + result0.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If it proves that this question better serves as just a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995988 better explaining the code, then I'm happy to modify to that.

Comment: I edited your question's code slightly. In addition to adding imports to make it compile (to make your question satisfy "reproducible" in "minimal, reproducible example"), I tweaked the style of the two `if` statements to remove extraneous differences between them, though without changing the behavior at all (to make your question satisfy "minimal" in "minimal, reproducible example").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joseph's right! You just inverted the order of the method's object and operand.  The `String.contains` method is to be called on the Strings of the `result2` Stream.

Moreover, you don't need to use any `for` loop to compute this result, both Lists can be converted into Streams, hence avoiding to mixing unnecessarily imperative and reactive styles on the same method.

Here is a Streams-only version of your program:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> result0 = Arrays.asList("/Videos/Templates/file.mp4", "/Videos/Templates/file2.mp4", "/Videos/Templates/file3.mp4");
        List<String> result2 = Arrays.asList("/Videos/Templates/file.mp4.sha256");

        result0.parallelStream()
            .filter(item0 -> result2.parallelStream()
                                .anyMatch(item2 -> item2.contains(item0)))
            .forEach(item0 -> System.out.println("sha matches files: " + item0));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `contains` is not a commutative operator. For example, "lightning" contains "light", but "light" does not contain "lightning". In your case, `"/Videos/Templates/file.mp4.sha256"` contains `"/Videos/Templates/file.mp4"`, but `"/Videos/Templates/file.mp4"` does not contain `"/Videos/Templates/file.mp4.sha256"`.

(In case it isn't clear, `foo::bar` is equivalent to `x -> foo.bar(x)`, so `finalResult.get(finalI)::contains` is equivalent to `x -> finalResult.get(finalI).contains(x)`.)