# Android WebView add more URL parameter values

Tags: android

I am using the following code to open default browser if links are external.
But so far I can only add two domains (or names).
How can I add more ?
If the link contains the word "facebook" it will open out side the app. I want to add more names/doamins in there.

```
if (url.contains("facebook") || url.contains("flipkart")) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
    startActivity(intent)
    webView.goBack()
    return true
} else {
    view?.loadUrl(url)
}
```

already tried

```
if (url.contains("facebook,youtube") || url.contains("flipkart")) {
```

and

```
if (url.contains("facebook","youtube") || url.contains("flipkart")) {
```

The only working method I got is following, is there a better option?

```
if (url.contains("facebook") || url.contains("flipkart") || url.contains("youtube")) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more by adding more `OR` operators like this:

```
if (url.contains("facebook") || url.contains("flipkart") || 
    url.contains("youtube")) {
```

If things are getting messier, you can create an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> domains = new ArrayList<String>();
domains.add("facebook");
domains.add("flipkart");
domains.add("youtube");
```

Then create a function:

```
private boolean checkDomain(){
  for(String domain: domains){
    if (url.contains(domain)){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And use it in your `if` statement:

```
if(checkDomain(url)){
   //Open URL in external browser
} else {
   //Display URL in your webview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ArrayList or String array,

```
String[] items = {"facebook", "flipkart", "stackoverflow"};
String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992100/";
```

Then create a check function :

```
public static boolean checkUrls(String inputStr, String[] items) {
    return Arrays.stream(items).anyMatch(inputStr::contains);
}
```

And use this method in your if statement:

```
if( checkUrls(url)){
    //Open URL in out side the app
} else {
    //Display URL in your app
}
```